# non-greedy regular expression for JavaScript

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to match all external resource in the CSS. For example, the `content` contains 2 resources like `//cdn.com/roboto-regular.eot` and `//cdn.com/roboto-bold.eot`.

```
var reg = /\/\/.*\.(js|css|jpg|eot)[^\/\/]/ig; 

var content="url(//cdn.com/roboto-regular.eot);src:url(//cdn.com/roboto-bold.eot#iefix)"; 

while ((match = reg.exec(content)) != null) console.log('match', match);
```

But the expression results in `"//cdn.com/roboto-regular.eot);src:url(//cdn.com/roboto-bold.eot#"`

How can I make the expression non-greedy so that I can get every match?

Answer (score 0):

You could exclude some characters from the list of matching characters :

```js
var reg = /\/\/[^)(]*\.(js|css|jpg|eot)/ig;
var content="url(//cdn.com/roboto-regular.eot);src:url(//cdn.com/roboto-bold.eot#iefix)"; 
while ((match = reg.exec(content)) != null) console.log('match', match);
```

`[^)(]` means `everything except ")" and "("`.

Comment: can use non-capturing group : `(?:js|css|jpg|eot)`, to avoid unnecessary capturing.

Comment: I know @AshishRanjan, but who said that it is unnecessary :-P

Answer (score 0):

Make the `.*` quantity in your regex lazy (or non greedy).

I think the only issue here is that `.*` was consuming everything from the start of the first match all the way to the end of the last match.

```js
var reg = /\/\/.*?\.(?:js|css|jpg|eot)[^\/\/]/ig; 

var content="The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. \n url(//cdn.com/roboto-regular.eot); some more stuff here src:url(//cdn.com/roboto-bold.eot#iefix)"; 

while ((match = reg.exec(content)) != null) console.log('match', match);
```

**Output:**

```
match //cdn.com/roboto-regular.eot),eot
match //cdn.com/roboto-bold.eot#,eot
```

## Demo

Comment: can use non-capturing group : `(?:js|css|jpg|eot)`, to avoid unnecessary capturing.